# How to get the list of "jar's" used by an android application?

Tags: android, jar

I would like to find the list of "libraries" (not "shared libraries") that are in used by an Application ?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You have to go trough analyzer tool  like [this](http://www.dependency-analyzer.org/). Quoting introduction:

> The purpose of this tool is to analyze Java™ class files in order to learn more about the dependencies between those classes.